# Program calculating incorrect averages

Tags: java

This program should allow more than one users (student) to enter his exam and project scores for multiple subjects then outputs the averages scores separately, then calculate the overall average based on  the addition of 20% of project score and  80% of exam.

The problem am having is that the averages results for the first student is correct but the program loops to the next student the averages are incorrect.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averages4{

public static void main(String[] args) {


String name1;
int sub, counter, num1; 


double project = 0.0, exam1 = 0.0, avg = 0.0,avg1 = 0.0,sum = 0.0,avgall = 0.0,sum1 = 0.0;


 Scanner inputStudent = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Enter the number of students to record scores then press enter: ");
  int student = inputStudent.nextInt(); 
      for (int z = 1; z <= student; z++) //this loops the entire program based on the the number of students.
       {

          Scanner inputFirstname = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("\nPlease enter your first name");
          name1 = inputFirstname.nextLine();

          System.out.println("First name: "+ name1);



             System.out.print("MENU TO CHOOSE FROM:\n");    

             System.out.println("1.Spanish \n 2. Biology\n 3. Chemistry \n" 
             + " 4.Physics\n");


             Scanner inputRegnum1 = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("How many subjects do you what to calculate scores for? "
                    + "Please enter.\n ");
             counter = inputRegnum1.nextInt();

                  { 
                   for (int x = 1; x <= counter; x++) /*This for loop keeps a count on the
                                                           number of subjects chosen.*/
                   { 
                      System.out.println("Choose your subject(s)\n");
                       Scanner test3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        sub  = test3.nextInt();
                          System.out.println(" ");

                         //switch used to select subjects.
                         switch (sub) {
                         case 1: System.out.println("Subject: 1. Spanish");break;
                         case 2: System.out.println("Subject: 2. Biology");break;
                         case 3: System.out.println("Subject: 3. Chemistry");break;
                         case 4: System.out.println("Subject: 4. Phyics");break;
                         default: System.out.println("Invalid option. Please choose option 1 - 4");break;
                                  }

                          }
                           Scanner test2 = new Scanner(System.in);  
                           System.out.println("\n\nHow many averages should I calculate for each subject?");

                          num1 = test2.nextInt();     


                            Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
                            System.out.println("Enter each of the "+ num1 + " project scores for the " +counter+" subject(s) and press enter\n");

                             //This for loop keeps a count on the total number of project scores.
                           for (int y = 1; y <= num1; y++){ 
                           project = test.nextDouble();
                           sum = sum + project; // calculates the total project score sums.

                          //outputs the project scores.);
                          System.out.println("The project score recorded is "+project); 
                          } 

                         avg = sum / num1; //calculates the project average.
                         System.out.println("\nThe project average recorded is  " + avg);
                        }


                         Scanner test1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                         System.out.println("Enter each of the "+ num1 + " examination scores for the " +counter+" subject(s) and press enter\n");

                        for (int y = 1; y <= num1; y++){ //keep count of the number of assignments.

                        exam1 = test1.nextDouble();
                        sum1 = sum1 + exam1;

                         System.out.println("\nThe examination score recorded is "+exam1);  
                        }


                       avg1 = sum1 / num1;//calculates the project average.

                       System.out.println("\nThe examination average recorded is  " + avg1);


                      avgall = (avg*.2) + (avg1 * .8);//calculates the overall average.
                      System.out.println("\nThe overall average is  "+ avgall);//outputs the overall average.



                      System.out.println("\n Average project score: "+  avg);
                      System.out.println("\n Average Exam score: "+  avg1);
                      System.out.println("\n Average Overall score: "+  avgall);


                 }

              }
           }
```

Example:  results

```
First student – results for 2 subjects
  Project score recorded is: 65.0
  Project score recorded is: 70.0
  Average project score: 67.5

 The examination score recorded is 55.0
 The examination score recorded is 60.0
 Average Exam score: 57.5
 Average Overall score: 59.5



 Second student – results for 2 subjects
Incorrect results.

The project score recorded is 50.0
The project score recorded is 55.0
Average project score: 120.0

The examination score recorded is 45.0
The examination score recorded is 50.0

Average Exam score: 105.0
Average Overall score: 108.0
```

Comment: Try debugging, you're probably not clearing a variable correctly.

Comment: You should also list what you've attempted to solve the problem rather than just the code/problem

Comment: At a quick glance and from what @Taylor said, try to declare/initialize the variables inside the for-loop so that each student will get "their own" test results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to "zero" everything out in the second loop. It *seems* to work when I did this. Emphasis on the *seems* as it's hard to follow the flow of the program. Try this out and see what happens

```
for (int x = 1; x <= counter; x++) /*
                                     * This for loop keeps a
                                     * count on the number of
                                     * subjects chosen.
                                     */

{

    project = 0.0; exam1 = 0.0; avg = 0.0; avg1 = 0.0; sum = 0.0; avgall = 0.0; sum1 = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the incorrect average (120), and compare to what the correct average should be (52.5), you'll quickly find that the difference is nothing but the previous student's average (67.5).

With this discovery in mind, the problem is then evident. The variables being used to keep track of each student's average are not being re-initialized to zero for each new student. The bigger issue really is that the variables are not correctly scoped.

Why define the holding variables at the top of the method that operates on all students when they're specific to a student?

```
//int studentTotal = 0; //Don't define it here.
for each student {
    int studentTotal = 0;  //Define variables in the narrowest scope
    for each score {
        studentTotal = studentTotal + score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum1 = sum1 + exam1;
```

You add to sum1 inside your loops, but never reset sum1 to be 0 after going to another student. Initialize your sums inside the loop going though all students or just assign 0 to it at the beginning of that loop.

Comment: Thank you @Byakuya, I realize that - big help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum` and `sum1` are getting accumulated for all the scores and for all the students. You would want to being them within the loop iterating over all the students.

```
for (int z = 1; z <= student; z++) 
    {
    sum = 0.0;
    sum1 = 0.0;

    Scanner inputFirstname = new Scanner(System.in);
...
```

Comment: Thank you @PopoFibo, I realize that the scores were accumulating.Thanks again.